# Android KeyStore.getInstance("RSA") is not working

Tags: android, ssl, keystore, ras

im trying to implement SSL connection on android, but i have a problem when i try to load my keystore, but i when i call KeyStore.getInstance("RSA") i got this exception.

03-26 12:19:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(6465): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore RSA implementation not found

```
 private KeyStore loadKeyStore() {
     if (keyStore != null) {
         Log.i("WSclient::KeyStore", " keyStore!=null");
         return keyStore; 
     }

     try {
         Log.i("WSclient::KeyStore", " keyStore.getInstancel");
         keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("RSA");
         Log.i("WSclient::KeyStore", " keyStore:: inputStream");
         InputStream in =  context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);
         try {
             Log.i("WSclient::KeyStore", " keyStore.load");
             keyStore.load(in, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
         } finally {
             in.close();
         }

         return keyStore;
     } catch (Exception e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says it all. There is no such thing as an RSA keystore. There are JKS keystores, PCKS#11 keystores, WindowsMY keystores, all kinds of things. What kind yours is, only you know.

Comment: ok, i think im lost, the person who send me he keystore show me the command line that he used to generate it, and it has RSA on it

Comment: Hey, you were totally right, the keystore was on JKS and i just had ton converse it to BKS, then KeyStore.getInstance("BKS") worked.
Thanks

Comment: The *key* was RSA. The *keystore* was JKS.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private/public key pair for the RSA algorithm as follows:

```
Calendar calendarValidityStart = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar calendarValidityEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarValidityEnd.add(Calendar.YEAR, 99);

KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
        .setAlias("MyKeyAlias")
        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + "MyKeyAlias"))
        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1337))
        .setStartDate(calendarValidityStart.getTime())
        .setEndDate(calendarValidityEnd.getTime())
        .build();

KeyPairGenerator kpGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
        "RSA",
        "AndroidKeyStore");

kpGenerator.initialize(spec);

KeyPair keyPair = kpGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

You can later retrieve the key pair from the KeyStore as follows:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
keyStore.load(null);
KeyStore.Entry keyStoreEntry = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
```

See the Android Developers [BasicAndroidKeyStore](http://developer.android.com/samples/BasicAndroidKeyStore/index.html) Sample for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to have

```
private KeyFactory keyStore;
```

`keyStore` must be `KeyFactory` type.

```
 //keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("RSA");
 keyStore = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
```

See this example:
**[How to use keystore in Java to store private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890313/how-to-use-keystore-in-java-to-store-private-key)**

Comment: Variable names are just conventions indeed, but calling a `KeyFactory` "`keyStore`" doesn't seem like a great idea. From the rest of the code in this question, it seems fair to assume `keyStore` was meant to be a instance of `KeyStore`.