# KeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair() in Android 7.1.1

Tags: android, android-keystore, key-pair, android-7.1-nougat

We have seen an influx of the following exceptions and only for Android 7.1.1 (API 25). Has something changed in 7.1.1 to make this fail?

```
java.security.ProviderException: Failed to load generated key pair from keystore
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.loadKeystoreKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:518)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:470)
```

Sanitized code below (may have slight copy paste bugs)

```
 KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
    String certInfo = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "CN=%s, OU=%s", new Object[]{"KeyName", context.getPackageName()});
  generator.initialize(new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)).setAlias("KeyName").setSubject(new X500Principal(certInfo)).setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE).setStartDate(start).setEndDate(end).build());
  generator.generateKeyPair();
```

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this error before and it's most likely caused by the deprecation of [KeyPairGeneratorSpec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.html), for API > 23 you should be using [KeyGenParameterSpec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.html) instead.

If you are targeting an API lower than 23 I suggest you to use some mechanism to use different specs depending on the API level.

```
AlgorithmParameterSpec spec;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS, purposes)
                 .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + KEY_ALIAS))
                 .setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.TEN)
                 .setCertificateNotBefore(start.getTime())
                 .setCertificateNotAfter(end.getTime())
                 .build();
} else {
    spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(Application.getApp().getApplicationContext())
                 .setAlias(KEY_ALIAS)
                 .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + KEY_ALIAS))
                 .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.TEN)
                 .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                 .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                 .build();
}
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, AndroidKeyStore);
kpg.initialize(spec);
kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

The crash is probably because some manufacturers may remove deprecated methods on their latest android builds, which is the reason it won't crash on all devices using API > 23 but only on some of them.

This matter has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269954/keypairgeneratorspec-deprecated) in SO before.